# How to read attribute using jquery on input variable with variable selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to reload a particular div, which has an id corresponding to a table element's id... (the div has only one table child).

the alert says tID is undefined.

javascript:

```
function (msg) {
         var tID = $("table", msg).attr('id');
         alert(tID);
         $("#reloadme_"+tID).html(msg);
}
```

html:

```
 <div id="reloadme_2036">

        <table id="2036"  class="customCSSclass">
            ...table contents...
        </table>

   </div>
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: What exactly are you supplying for `msg`?

Comment: what is the value of msg variable? Why you pass this to the selector $("table", msg) ?

Comment: random shot: try `var tID = $(msg).find('table').attr('id');` in case `msg` is a HTML string.

Comment: A HTML string, something like:
        <table id="2036"  class="customCSSclass">
            ...table contents...
        </table>

Comment: Fabricio, thanks for the try. It also says undefined for that line.

Comment: If the string looks like that, then `var tID = $(msg).filter('table').attr('id');` or more simply `var tID = $(msg).attr('id');` if the string only contains the table.

Comment: Worked :) THANK YOU!!

So why does 'filter' work and 'find' not?

Comment: I'll submit an answer in a sec. `=]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) looks for *descendants* of the current set of elements inside the jQuery object, you should use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) which filters the elements in the jQuery object itself:

```
$('<table id="001">[...]</table>')
//the jQuery object will contain a reference to the parsed <table> element,
//so you have to .filter() the jQuery object itself to extract it
```

Of course, if it is the only element inside the jQuery object, there is no need for filtering. `=]`

Also, you'd use `.find` for e.g. looking for `tr`/`td`s (or any other element(s)) that are descendant of the `table` element referenced inside of your jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks mate, but it appears I can't vote this up because I am so disreputable :P

Comment: @ninjamario no problem, you can still tick it as the accepted answer clicking in the "V" below the up/down buttons. `=]`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you're looking for?

```
function reload(msg) {
  var tID = msg.match(/id="(\d{1,4})"/i)[1]; //find 1 to 4 digits in the id attribute
  alert(tID);  //alerts 2036
  $("#reloadme_"+tID).html(msg); //adds the content to the div
}
reload('<table id="2036" class="customCSSclass"> ...table contents... </table>');
```

If so, what you are likely looking for is javascript's .match() method which will find the id number within a string.

Check out the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/Z3W3Z/).

Comment: Thanks for an alternative solution :) match() seems like a useful function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try like this

```
var msg='<table id="2036"  class="customCSSclass"></table>';
alert($(msg).attr("id"));
```